Why does `dict(id=1, **{'id': 2})` sometimes raise `KeyError: 'id'` instead of a TypeError?
Normally, if you try to pass multiple values for the same keyword argument, you get a TypeError:
In [1]: dict(id=1, **{'id': 2})
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [1], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 dict(id=1, **{'id': 2})

TypeError: dict() got multiple values for keyword argument 'id'

But if you do it while handling another exception, you get a KeyError instead:
In [2]: try:
   ...:     raise ValueError('foo') # no matter what kind of exception
   ...: except:
   ...:     dict(id=1, **{'id': 2}) # raises: KeyError: 'id'
   ...: 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [2], in <cell line: 1>()
      1 try:
----> 2     raise ValueError('foo') # no matter what kind of exception
      3 except:

ValueError: foo

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [2], in <cell line: 1>()
      2     raise ValueError('foo') # no matter what kind of exception
      3 except:
----> 4     dict(id=1, **{'id': 2})

KeyError: 'id'

What's going on here? How could a completely unrelated exception affect what kind of exception dict(id=1, **{'id': 2}) throws?
For context, I discovered this behavior while investigating the following bug report: https://github.com/tortoise/tortoise-orm/issues/1583
This has been reproduced on CPython 3.11.8, 3.10.5, and 3.9.5.

Do you understand why dict(id=1, id=2) is an error? Your code is effectively the same

@blues: They're not confused by the existence of an error. They're confused about why it's a different error than it would normally be.

Beside the point, but a bare except: is bad practice. Instead, use the specific exception you're expecting, i.e. except ValueError:. That said, it doesn't affect the problem, I just wanted to rule it out.

CPython 3.8.10 is also affected.

id is confusing too because it's a builtin python function.

@qwr It's used as a dict key, I don't think that's an issue/confusing and it's quite common/normal for objects to have an id field . Also, the built-in id function is rarely used.

@nocomment the builtin being rarely used is exactly why it's confusing.

@qwr How does that make it confusing?

@nocomment am I missing something, or is the dict key the function object id, not the string "id"?

@qwr It's the string "id". With dict(key=value), the key acts as a parameter keyword, and thus is a string. For example, you can't use an integer as a key this way; dict(1=2) will fail: all keys need to be strings when using dict(). Thus id is a string in this context.

@9769953 oh I see. it's different than the dict literal syntax with curly braces.

@qwr Yes, it's one of those Python gotchas. It gets worse when you use an iterable as argument, e.g. dict(zip(range(10), range(20, 30))), which does allow for all kind of non-string objects; it is equivalent to the much clearer list comprehension: {key: value for key, value in zip(range(10), range(20, 30))}.

This looks like a Python bug.
The code that's supposed to raise the TypeError works by detecting and replacing an initial KeyError, but this code doesn't work right. When the exception occurs in the middle of another exception handler, the code that should raise the TypeError fails to recognize the KeyError. It ends up letting the KeyError through, instead of replacing it with a TypeError.
The bug appears to be gone on 3.12, due to changes in the exception implementation.

Here's the deep dive, for the CPython 3.11.8 source code. Similar code exists on 3.10 and 3.9.
As we can see by using the dis module to examine the bytecode for dict(id=1, **{'id': 2}):
In [1]: import dis

In [2]: dis.dis("dict(id=1, **{'id': 2})")
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (dict)
              2 LOAD_CONST               3 (())
              4 LOAD_CONST               0 ('id')
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              8 BUILD_MAP                1
             10 LOAD_CONST               0 ('id')
             12 LOAD_CONST               2 (2)
             14 BUILD_MAP                1
             16 DICT_MERGE               1
             18 CALL_FUNCTION_EX         1
             20 RETURN_VALUE

Python uses the DICT_MERGE opcode to merge two dicts, to build the final keyword argument dict.
The relevant part of the DICT_MERGE code is as follows:
            if (_PyDict_MergeEx(dict, update, 2) < 0) {
                format_kwargs_error(tstate, PEEK(2 + oparg), update);
                Py_DECREF(update);
                goto error;
            }

It uses _PyDict_MergeEx to attempt to merge two dicts, and if that fails (and raises an exception), it uses format_kwargs_error to try to raise a different exception.
When the third argument to _PyDict_MergeEx is 2, that function will raise a KeyError for duplicate keys, inside the dict_merge helper function. This is where the KeyError comes from.
Once the KeyError is raised, format_kwargs_error has the job of replacing it with a TypeError. It tries to do so with the following code:
    else if (_PyErr_ExceptionMatches(tstate, PyExc_KeyError)) {
        PyObject *exc, *val, *tb;
        _PyErr_Fetch(tstate, &exc, &val, &tb);
        if (val && PyTuple_Check(val) && PyTuple_GET_SIZE(val) == 1) {

but this code is looking for an unnormalized exception, an internal way of representing exceptions that isn't exposed to Python-level code. It expects the exception value to be a 1-element tuple containing the key that the KeyError was raised for, instead of an actual exception object.
Exceptions raised inside C code are usually unnormalized, but not if they occur while Python is handling another exception. Unnormalized exceptions cannot handle exception chaining, which occurs automatically for exceptions raised inside an exception handler. In this case, the internal _PyErr_SetObject routine will automatically normalize the exception:
    exc_value = _PyErr_GetTopmostException(tstate)->exc_value;
    if (exc_value != NULL && exc_value != Py_None) {
        /* Implicit exception chaining */
        Py_INCREF(exc_value);
        if (value == NULL || !PyExceptionInstance_Check(value)) {
            /* We must normalize the value right now */

Since the KeyError has been normalized, format_kwargs_error doesn't understand what it's looking at. It lets the KeyError through, instead of raising the TypeError it's supposed to.

On Python 3.12, things are different. The internal exception representation has been changed, so any raised exception is always normalized. Thus, the Python 3.12 version of format_kwargs_error looks for a normalized exception instead of an unnormalized exception, and if _PyDict_MergeEx has raised a KeyError, the code will recognize it:
    else if (_PyErr_ExceptionMatches(tstate, PyExc_KeyError)) {
        PyObject *exc = _PyErr_GetRaisedException(tstate);
        PyObject *args = ((PyBaseExceptionObject *)exc)->args;
        if (exc && PyTuple_Check(args) && PyTuple_GET_SIZE(args) == 1) {


FWIW, it seems to be resolved. An instruction was added (RETURN_CONST). The try..except gives a TypeError in 3.12.1.

@Timeless: It's not the RETURN_CONST instruction. They changed the exception representation. Unnormalized exceptions are pretty much gone now. format_kwargs_error now looks for a normalized exception, and finds it.
